# How to set default indent on bullets in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I know that I can use the `List Bullet` style in order to make bullets flush to the left margin in Word 2007; however, when I use that and try to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to make the next line a deeper level, the bullet icon is not changed.

Is there a way to change the default indentation when using the `Bullet List`? Ideally, this would be for every document I create, forevermore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select "Define New Bullet" from the drop down to the right of the bullet you can define a new bullet style.

[image]

[image]

To change the indent you'll have to change the paragraph style that applies to bullet lists.

You'll then need to save that in a template "Save As > Word Template". You can either overwrite the existing Normal.dot or save it as a new one. Overwriting Normal.dot will mean that you don't have to select your new template when creating a new document.

Comment: The last bullet style selected is the new default. If you then save the document as a new word template (normal.dotm) and put it in the folder "C:\Users\<Your user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates".

Comment: +1 for red hand-drawn circles (oh wait, wrong site)